# Properly send NodeJS Buffer as form data to Spring boot

Tags: javascript, node.js, spring-boot

I have NodeJS application where I have image buffer `qrCode`

```
                const qrCodeData = Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');  //body received, not sure if base64 is correct  
                formData.append('qrCode',qrCodeData,"qrCode.jpg");
                axios({
                    method: "post",
                    url: `${SERVER_URL}${TICKET_VALIDATION}`,
                    data: formData,
                    headers: formData.getHeaders(),
                })
                    .then((res)=>console.log(res))
```

In Spring boot I catch this request

```
public TicketValidationResponse validateTicket(@RequestPart MultipartFile qrCode) throws ... {
    //Many lines omitted
var image = ImageIO.read(qrCode.getInputStream()) // image = null here
}
```

Actually all works in Postman.

So I am sure that its problem with passing image from NodeJS .

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

I changed in NodeJS

`const qrCodeData = Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');`

to

`const qrCodeData = Buffer.from(body);`